# how to compare the two fields in php with different table in mysql?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

1. //here is my updated code it now compares the current time with the 
   saved time in mysql but my problem is it only compares with the
   first added time what I need is the current time will compare it to
   the nearest time saved in mysql.

   ```
            <?php
           //Include the database configuration
           include 'config.php';
           //Get the data of the selected teacher
           $teacher = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT * FROM teacher_info
           WHERE IMEI = ? AND NFC = ?");
           $teacher->bindValue(1,$_GET['IMEI']);
           $teacher->bindValue(2,$_GET['NFC']);
           $teacher->execute();
           //Get the data
           $teacher_info = $teacher->fetch();


       //If there is such a teacher let the teacher enter
       if(!empty($teacher_info))
       {
           $time_out = $dbconnect->prepare("INSERT INTO time_out (teacher_id,name,NFC,IMEI,time_out) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW())");
           $time_out->bindValue(1,$teacher_info['teacher_id']);
           $time_out->bindValue(2,$teacher_info['name']);
           $time_out->bindValue(3,$teacher_info['NFC']);
           $time_out->bindValue(4,$teacher_info['IMEI']);
           $time_out->execute();
       }
       ?>
       <!doctype html>
       <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <title>Welcome!</title>
       </head>
       <body>
       <h1>
           <?php
           //If there is such a teacher,welcome him/her
           if(!empty($teacher_info))
           {
               echo 'Welcome '.$teacher_info['name'].'! Your NFC is '.$teacher_info['NFC'];
           }
           else
           {
               echo 'You are not registered.';
           }
           ?>
       </h1>



       </body>
       </html>


      //Hope you can help me out
   ```

Comment: Use join of sql then use an if statements.

Comment: put some code what you have tried

Comment: please show what have you made so far

Comment: the two fields are time and time_in and it is saved with different table in mysql. so for example the professor have a class from 8:30-10:00 am and he exactly time in at 8:30 he will be notify "You are on time" and if not "You are late"

Comment: @DishaV. here's my code to get the time he time in

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro In which table is `time_in` saved in?

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari in the Insert Into time_in. the sample code I put is for time out but its the same with the time in. I'm sorry the code I posted is for time out but its the same with the time in.hope you can help me

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro  So `time_in` is a table itself? Do you want to compare the time with the current time?.

Comment: yes @HawasKaPujaari the time_in is a table itself. Can you show me some sample on how to do this because I'm just a beginner in php. hope you can help me.

Comment: The conversation on an answer below has carried on for ~50 comments, and is starting to include requests like "please fix it for me". These are probably indicators that the question is too broad. OP, would it be a good idea to do some tutorials first, so that the concepts are clearer for you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a `time_in` column in the table `time_in`

```
if($stmt = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT time_in from time_in")){
$stmt->bind_param("s", $time_in); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$cur_time = time();
if($time_in === $cur_time){
echo "Teacher is on time";
}
}
```

This is mainly an idea about how things should be going. There's always room for improvement. To be precise, you should give a `teacher_id` in the `time_in` table so that the respective teacher's time is selected only.

**EDIT:**

```
 if($stmt = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT time_in from time_in")){
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $time_in); 
   $stmt->execute(); 
 if($stmtt = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT time from profschedule")){
  $stmtt->bind_param("s", $time); 
  $stmt->execute(); 
 if($time_in === $time)
  echo "Teacher is on time";
}}}
```

Although, this is poorly written but the whole point of it is to give you the IDEA about how to approach after inspecting your perspective in the comments.

Comment: Thank you so much. But what if I have a time_in column in my table time_in and I want to compare the time_in in the saved  schedule of the professor in another table which is table profschedule that contains the column time. And I want to compare the column time_in from column time.

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro Simply fetch the column `time` from `profschedule` table and then put an `if-statement` to compare the time with the already fetched time `time_in` from `time_in` table somewhat like I did in the above answer. To make it even simpler, put a sql join and run only one query to select the times from both of the tables.

Comment: if($stmt = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT time from time")){
$stmt->bind_param("s", $time); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$cur_time = time_in();
if($time_in === $time){
echo "Teacher is on time";
}
}   //Just like that?

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro This `$cur_time = time_in();` is not needed anymore since you are comparing the times from tables now. Ps. In the answer above, right below `$stmt->execute();` put the second query and the `if-statement` `if($time_in === $time){ //`

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro No, that's not the way, look at my edit for a better understanding

Comment: if($stmt = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT time_in from time_in")){
$stmt->bind_param("s", $time_in); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$sql = "SELECT time FROM profschedule";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if($time_in === $time){
echo "Teacher is on time";
}
}   //is this correct? Or you can please show me how your code looks like?

Comment: I get it now. I will try run it and I will give you if it works on me thank you very much and God bless.

Comment: Clearly, No. You're mixing up the `mysql_*` API's with `mysqli`.

Comment: I got an error and it says Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\test\time_in\index.php on line 49

Comment: I add this after the </h1> <h2>
  <?php
 if($stmt = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT time_in from time_in")){
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $time_in); 
   $stmt->execute(); 
 if($stmtt = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT time from profschedule")){
  $stmtt->bind_param("s", $time); 
  $stmt->execute(); 
 if($time_in === $time)
  echo "Teacher is on time";
}}
?>
</h2>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro Errr. try `bindParam`, not `bind_param`  Study more here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I got an error when I changed it to bindParam. It says Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\test\time_in\index.php on line 49

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro I would suggest you to move to simple mysqli approach since you're just starting off: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I will try to decode it again and I will give you updates after that.

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro Sure, and If it resolves the problem don't forget to tick my answer :)

Comment: I got an error and it says Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::bindParam() in C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\test\time\index.php on line 44

Comment: here's what I add <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "time");

 /* check connection */
 if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
     printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
     exit();
 }


 if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT time_in from time_in")){
     $result->bindParam("s", $time_in); 
     $result->execute(); 
  if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT from from time")){
    $result->bindParam("s", $from); 
    $result->execute(); 
  if($time_in === $from)
   echo "Teacher is on time";
  

   }}
 ?>

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro Try this: `<?php 
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "time"); 
 if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { 
 printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error); 
 exit(); }
 if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT time_in from time_in")){ 
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $time_in = $row['time_in'];
 }
 if($results = $mysqli->query("SELECT from from time")){ 
 while($row2 = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
 $from = $row2['from'];
 }
 if($time_in === $from) 
 echo "Teacher is on time"; }} 
 ?>`

Comment: now it doesn't show any errors but It doesn't show "teacher is on time" or teacher is late"? what do you think the problem is?

Comment: I add your code after the </html> on my code i posted

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro enable error reporting, that helps you understand if you have any errors. and also add an `else-statement` `if($time_in === $from) echo "Teacher is on time"; else echo "Teacher is late";` Check now?

Comment: Here's the code  <?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "time"); 
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
 exit();
 } 
 if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT time_in from time_in")){ 
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
 $time_in = $row['time_in']; } 
 if($results = $mysqli->query("SELECT from from time")){
 while($row2 = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
 $from = $row2['from']; } 
 if($time_in == $from) 
echo "Teacher is on time"; 
}} 
else
{
echo "You are late";
}
?>
 </h1>

Comment: and after the </h1> I have this code  <?php
    //If there is such a teacher,welcome him/her
    if(!empty($teacher_info))
    {
        echo 'Welcome '.$teacher_info['name'].'! Your NFC is '.$teacher_info['NFC'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'You are not registered.';
    }
    ?>

Comment: When I run it in my browser it shows Time In at: September 12, 2015 9:06:pm
Welcome seer! Your NFC is 12345     //but it doesn't show "On time" or "Late"

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro that has an extra closing curly bracket `}` after the `if-statement`

Comment: try this: `<?php 
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "time"); 
 if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { 
 printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error); 
 exit(); }
 if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT time_in from time_in")){ 
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $time_in = $row['time_in'];
 }
 if($results = $mysqli->query("SELECT from from time")){ 
 while($row2 = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
 $from = $row2['from'];
 }
 if($time_in === $from) 
 echo "Teacher is on time";
else
 echo "Teacher is late";
 }} 
 ?>`

Comment: I try your code but it output the same result "Time In at: September 12, 2015 9:25:pm
Welcome seer! Your NFC is 12345"

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro put the comparison code before you echo the Time in.

Comment: maybe its because of the config.php file I have //here is the code for the config.php      <?php
//For correct time
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
 echo "<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>Time In at: </span>". date('F j, Y g:i:a  ');
try
{
    $dbconnect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;
          dbname=time',
                               'root','');
    $dbconnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $error)
{
    die('Sorry for the inconvenience. We are fixing it soon.');
}
?>

Comment: do you want to see my code I will upload it to dropbox?

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro to keep things simple and not flood the comments section, check the following things 1) config.php using mysqli and not PDO 2) proper credentials given in the connection. 3) correct names of table/columns given. The rest is already been said.

Comment: I'm sorry If I have so many questions and I can't fix it immediately. I change now the config.php connection to mysqli and now the error I get Fatal error: Call to a member function bindValue() on boolean in C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\test\time\index.php on line 7

Comment: <?php
//Include the database configuration
include 'config.php';
//Get the data of the selected teacher
$teacher = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM time
WHERE IMEI = ? AND NFC = ?");
$teacher->bindValue(1,$_GET['IMEI']);
$teacher->bindValue(2,$_GET['NFC']);
$teacher->execute();
//Get the data
$teacher_info = $teacher->fetch();

//If there is such a teacher let the teacher enter
if(!empty($teacher_info))
{
   // what is the thing I can replace for bindValue?

Comment: `$imei = $_GET['IMEI'];
$nfc = $_GET['NFC']; 
$teacher = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM time WHERE IMEI = '$imei' AND NFC = '$nfc'");
while($row = $teacher->fetch_assoc()) {
  //fecth all the info here
 }` you should spend some time studying the basics :) :http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage

Comment: I feel shy about you because I have so many questions and now I still dont get it. I still have an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'teacher_id' (T_STRING), expecting ']' in C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\test\time\index.php on line 25<?php
//Include the database configuration
include 'config.php';
//Get the data of the selected teacher
$imei = $_GET['IMEI'];
$nfc = $_GET['NFC'];
$teacher = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM time
WHERE IMEI = '$imei' AND NFC = '$nfc'");

while($row = $teacher->fetch_assoc()) 
{ 
 $imei = $row['IMEI'];
 $nfc = $row['NFC];

}

$teacher->execute();

Comment: //this is the next code after the $teacher->execute();                              //Get the data
$teacher_info = $teacher->fetch();

//If there is such a teacher let the teacher enter
if(!empty($time))
{
    $time_in = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO time_in (teacher_id,name,NFC,IMEI,time_in) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW())");
    $time_in = $_GET['teacher_id'];
    $time_in = $_GET['name'];
    $time_in = $_GET['NFC'];
    $time_in = $_GET['IMEI'];
    $time_in->execute();
}
?>

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro The error denotes that you're not receiving the teacher_id correctly using $_GET[]; try to echo and see if it really has any value.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/smz6lcn1tc99agp/time.zip?dl=0                        can you please really help me out to fix this. Just import the time.sql database to your xampp server.please download the file. I really need your help. God bless you.

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro I had a look at your files, your index.php file had several errors, starting from the invalid use of `$_GET[];` and as well as a missing ' on line 13 `$nfc = $row['NFC];` should be `$nfc = $row['NFC'];`  Where are you getting `$imei = $_GET['IMEI'];
$nfc = $_GET['NFC'];` from? there is no link attached or anything.

Comment: can you please fix it for me? so I can know what is my error?

Comment: if you have a dropbox account or any sharing applications .you can post here the link so I can download it and realized what are my errors. Thank you so much and God bless.

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro I fixed the errors in the index.php and addschedule.php but the logic still needs to be fixed by yourself. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5phibnbri86ra64/AAAv564QL3d0hHBLr7sdonYDa?dl=0

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the meaning of that?                               // the following two variables are undefined!
$imei = $_GET['IMEI'];
$nfc = $_GET['NFC'];

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro you are fetching the values using `$_GET[];` the question is _from where?_

Comment: I'm trying to get the IMEI and NFC registered in the table time. so when I put this link on my browser http://localhost/test/time/IMEI=12345&NFC=12345 the time I access the link is my time in and the time schedule saved from the from column in table time will compare and will give a notification if he/she is late or on time.

Comment: Can you please tell me what to do?

Comment: @MikeSeerjohnMarquezMaestro I have done a few changes to `index.php` have a look and try to understand the approach: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5phibnbri86ra64/AAAv564QL3d0hHBLr7sdonYDa?dl=0

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out to finish this but this not work for me when I put this on my browser localhost/test/time/IMEI=12345&NFC=12345 it's just echo this message "Teacher Added.
You are not registered.". what II need is when I put this on my browser localhost/test/time/?IMEI=12345&NFC=12345  It will show " Time in at ' ' Welcome seer Your Nfc is 12345 You are late or You are on time.  the from column in the table time will compare the time I access this link http://localhost/test/time/?IMEI=12345&NFC=12345 and will echo "You are late or on time".